# Single User authentication in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, authentication

I'm trying to build an internal admin system to get to grips with creating a Laravel app from scratch. Currently everything is public so I'm looking at implementing a very simple login system.

There will be no DB connection needed as we want a single user. We'll store the relevant username and password in the .env file most likely.

I feel like I've looked everywhere and haven't been able to find any tutorials covering this requirement! From everything I've read it seems I have to use a 'custom authentication driver' or possibly build my own user provider class but I have no idea how to go about this task.

The idea is that if the app is expanded in future we'd like to be able to just go back to using Laravel's built in db auth functionality. For this reason it would be nice to retain all the common methods relating to checking the current user, using auth middleware on my routes and managing login tokens etc.

Thanks in advance for any help offered.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense and less problems to just use the DB for and just put in one user? It seems to be way to much to write a new auth service just to use one skngle user stored in the env file.

Comment: I would just use an SQLite database which Laravel supports out-of-the-box. That way you don't have to rewrite anything and you can switch to a more robust DB like MySQL in the future.

Comment: @codedge I may well do that although the idea was to set up a solution **without** having to modify the database. The question was also born out of curiosity around modifying standard Laravel auth features as much as anything (I know the principles will be applicable for other issues). Thanks for the response!

Comment: @BrokenBinary Thanks, sounds like maybe I was making additional work for myself!